# makeStateKey from Angular Universal need to be unique or specific?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

Angular universal provide us to transfer state data from server to client only using the TransferState.

But i search for this kind of information on internet and don't find any response.

If i save the data on a key using TransferState i need to make this unique? Example:

```
this.USER_KEY = makeStateKey<User>('userAuthKey-');
```

or i must use like this

```
this.USER_KEY = makeStateKey<User>('userAuthKey-' + user.id);
```

When another client on another browser access this same page **he will retrieve the same data or don't?**

And one last question how Angular Universal store data from TransferState? Cookie?

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding goes, TransferState is more related to specific requests. That is you make a request for a page. That page has some data x in it. You save that data to transfer state and the request is served. Once it reaches the browser the data can be read. Now, while another request was in the server it also made use of a transfer state api but that to the context of another request. So for both cases the transfer state is being different. The user is only getting the data which was saved for their specific request.

But it is better to use unique key if possible, because if you further want to use the data for other processes it will help you to create a map

Answer (score 0):

The goal of the `TransferStateModule` is for the following scenario:
A visitor visits your website. Your backend SSR's the page, but this requires data from your database. Your backend reads the data from the db, and passes it on to NodeJS in order to render the page. Once this is done the visitor receives a response with all the information.

Next, the angular runtime is loaded, and re-renders the entire application after it was bootstrapped. The data that was inserted during SSR is all gone. Now the application has to perform an ajax call to fetch this data again. In case of theme colors or fonts this would cause a tripple-flash.

In order to prevent this loss of data, we can use the `TransferState` module:

```js
// Create a state-key outside your AppComponent
const backgroundOpacityState = makeStateKey<number>('backgroundOpacity');

export interface DataFromServer {
  backgroundOpacity: number;
}

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  backgroundOpacity = 1.00;
  constructor(
    private transferState: TransferState,
    @Optional() @Inject('DATA_FROM_SERVER') private dataFromServer: DataFromServer,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.backgroundOpacity = dataFromServer.backgroundOpacity;
      // Store the value received from the server in the TransferState (this happens during SSR).
      this.transferState.set<number>(backgroundOpacityState, dataFromServer.backgroundOpacity);
    } else {
      // Get the value back from the TransferState to prevent the opacity=1.0 while the angular app isn't loaded yet.
      this.backgroundOpacity = this.transferState.get<number>(backgroundOpacityState, null);
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you loaded the `BrowserTransferStateModule` in the `AppModule`, and the `ServerTransferStateModule` in the `AppServerModule`.

The background-opacity is to be read by your backend from the database, and passed to the `main.server.ts`:

Backend code:

```cs
public class SpaPrerenderingService : ISpaPrerenderingService {
    private readonly IParameterService parameterService;
    public SpaPrerenderingService(IParameterService parameterService) {
        this.parameterService = parameterService;
    }
    
    public async Task OnSupplyData(HttpContext httpContext, IDictionary<string, object> data) {
        var param = await parameterService.GetParameter("BackgroundOpacity");
        if (double.TryParse(param.Value, out var backgroundOpacity)) {
            data["backgroundOpacity"] = backgroundOpacity;
        }
    }
}
```

main.server.ts

```js
export default createServerRenderer(params => {
    const providers: StaticProvider[] = [
        { provide: 'DATA_FROM_SERVER', useValue: params.data },
    ]

    const options = {
        document: params.data.originalHtml,
        url: params.url,
        extraProviders: providers
    };

    const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
        ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
        : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

    return renderPromise.then(html => ({ html }));
});
```

By doing this, angular will create the following tag in the SSRed response:

```html
<script id="serverApp-state" type="application/json">
{
  &q;backgroundOpacity&q;:0.2
}
</script>
```

The result is that you **no longer** have the following scenario:

- User visits the website
- The backend reads a parameter from the database
- The backend renders the response on the server, using the information from the database
- The visitor receives the rendered response, which is rendered by the browser. The page is presented using the actual information from the server
- The angular app is bootstrapped. The value of the parameter is unknown
- The angular app sends a webrequest to retrieve the parameter from the database
- Angular can finally set the correct background opacity